# Firefox: First Time Hover Blink

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to change the background-image of an element on mouseover, and it works all fine and dandy in Chrome. But in Firefox it always blinks/flickers for a split second on the very first hover after loading the page.

I've already pre-loaded the images that are needed on `body:after`, and the developer console in Firefox shows that there is a "GET" request for the file in question. Yet it doesn't seem to be ready to get rendered on the first mouseover.

This is how I pre-load the image.

```
body:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    content: url(image.png);
}
```

I don't understand, why it's working flawlessly in Chrome, but Firefox produces the first-time flicker regardless of pre-loading or not. I do know about image sprites, but in my case, it's not a possibility.

Comment: can u make a demo fiddle

Comment: please create a code snippet of your working code. thanks

Comment: I don’t know if I could be bothered to pre-render an image either, if you told me upfront the space in which I should do so was 0 x 0 pixels.

Comment: Yeah, you're right 04FS. Modern browsers probably do too many "smart decisions" for a simple pre-loading trick like this. After all this I'm going for an image sprite regardless of my last statement in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it's already loaded from server, if some additional delay is seen then I would instead put both images (stacked or side-by-side) into a single image a.k.a. spritesheet.

Then on hover, shift the background-position to reveal the other half of the image.

For example, if the images are each 50x50, you could make one 100x50 image with both side-by-side. Let the normal state show the left half only (by keeping the element width to 50 and background-position 0 0) and then slide the background 50px left on hover, to reveal the right half:

```
background-position: -50px 0;
```

Comment: Agreed, using the "sliding doors" technique like this would be easier, less code, work everywhere, and less HTTP requests for images

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use an image sprite is because I was planning for a background transition to be added later. And it looks really weird if you do that with an image sprite.

But I've found a way to do it regardless (in this article): https://gordonlesti.com/css-background-transitions-with-image-sprites/